# update-rc.d command warning

Tags: startup

i am trying to add ssh deamon at startup but i am getting following problem

```
$ sudo update-rc.d ssh start 50 2 3 4 5 . stop 90 0 1 6 .

update-rc.d: warning:  stop runlevel arguments (0 1 6) do not match ssh Default-Stop values (none)    
 Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/ssh ...
   /etc/rc0.d/K90ssh -> ../init.d/ssh
   /etc/rc1.d/K90ssh -> ../init.d/ssh
   /etc/rc6.d/K90ssh -> ../init.d/ssh
   /etc/rc2.d/S50ssh -> ../init.d/ssh
   /etc/rc3.d/S50ssh -> ../init.d/ssh  
   /etc/rc4.d/S50ssh -> ../init.d/ssh  
   /etc/rc5.d/S50ssh -> ../init.d/ssh
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update-rc.d will try to modify the existing runlevel links. If they don't exist, it throws an error.

Try the default option to create the links.

```
update-rc.d -f script defaults
```

Comment: means i need to run update-rc.d -f script defaults every time before i run update-rc.d -f script start sequence_no runlevel .